# fancybox youtube overlay

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, fancybox, overlay

Hy there i have a youtube link and a fancybox images on a page but when i open the images the youtube video doesn't go in the background. but instead it goes on top of the image here is what the code looks like

```
<a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" href="http://xbmc.org/wp-content/gallery/aeon/aeon_home_watchmen.jpg" title="xbmc"><img alt="1" src="http://xbmc.org/wp-content/gallery/aeon/aeon_home_watchmen.jpg" width="105" height="75"/></a>



<iframe width="480" height="270"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/v_AxZXmPRVQ">
</iframe>
```

also this only happens in Google Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `wmode` to `opaque` of your youtube video like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/v_AxZXmPRVQ?wmode=opaque" width="480" height="270" ></iframe>
```

Comment: It works, just wondering what it actually means and why it affects the videos?

Comment: set the Window Mode (`wmode`) property of the SWF content to control layering and transparency of the content in the browser: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_